# Calculate with Demorgan

Tags: boolean-algebra

[image]

Find \$\overline Y\$.

I have got to \$(\overline A+ B)\cdot(\overline C+D) + (E \cdot \overline F)\$.

I want to make sure I've got it right. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: \$(\overline A+ \overline B)\cdot(\overline C +D) + (E \cdot \overline F)\$.

Comment: No, it is wrong. As you can see in the original expression `A` and `B` are both positive. But in the result `A` is inverted, but `B` is not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So just B has to be inverted. thats it, right?

Comment: I don't know. Actually I've got a simpler expression.

Comment: Well, It's $F*1$ in the right part. then you do de-morgan on everything and get the same expression I got.

Comment: Again, I have got a simpler expression. I am not saying yours is not correct (not going to check..).

Comment: I think the OR has to be before the AND, i.e. you are missing a set of parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Y = AB  + C \overline D (\overline E + F (G \overline H + 1))$$
$$Y = AB  + C \overline D (\overline E + F)$$
$$\overline Y = \overline{ AB  + C \overline D (\overline E + F)}$$

Take DeMorgan's.
$$\overline Y = \overline {AB} \bullet  \overline {C \overline D (\overline E + F )}$$
Take DeMorgan's.
$$\overline Y = (\overline A + \overline B) \bullet  (\overline C + \overline{\overline D} + \overline {(\overline E + F )})$$
$$\overline Y = (\overline A + \overline B) \bullet  (\overline C + D + \overline {(\overline E + F )})$$
One last time.
$$\overline Y = (\overline A + \overline B) \bullet  (\overline C + D +  (\overline {\overline E} \bullet \overline F ))$$
$$\overline Y = (\overline A + \overline B) \bullet  (\overline C + D +  ( E \bullet \overline F ))$$

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment, because I don't have 50 rep.

You can use Wolfram Alpha to minimize boolean logic.

For example:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A+%26%26+B+%7C%7C+C+%26%26+%7ED+%26%26+%28%7EE+%7C%7C+F+%26%26+%28G+%26%26+%7EH+%7C%7C+1%29%29